# Cloudflare 522 error - javascript client connecting to node server

Tags: node.js, cloudflare, node-https

I'm trying to connect to a nodejs https server from a apache web server hosted javascript client and I'm getting an error message : `522 - Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given indentifier`. The apache web server runs on the same domain/server as the node server and the servers are proxied by Cloudflare:

- Client app: https://www.example.com (apache web server on port 443)
- Node SERVER: https://www.example.com:2053

Both services run in the same server/machine. This is how I start nodejs server:

```
// Certificates are the same used by apache web server in Virtual Host 
// and were got from Cloud Flare Panel > SSL/TLS > Origin Server
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/cloudflare/example.com.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/cloudflare/example.com.pem'),
};

var socket = require('socket.io');
var http = require('https');

// Port 2053 was listed as a https port supported by Cloud Flare in
// https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/
var argv = require('optimist')
    .usage('Usage: --port [num]')
    .default({port: 2053})
    .argv;

var server = http.createServer(options, function(req, res) {
});

server.listen(argv.port);

var io = socket.listen(server);
```

This is how I connect to nodejs server from the javascript client:

```
let socket = io.connect("https://www.example.com:2053", {secure: true});
```

Any tips?

**Edit 1**
It works if I create the node server as http (instead of https).

Comment: You should use the docs on this error: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003011431-Troubleshooting-Cloudflare-5XX-errors
Providing the domain is critical to helping you. If you cannot provide the domain, I recommend contacting Cloudflare Support directly if you have a paid plan.

Comment: @RossJacobs thank you. I read the provided docs but I couldnt find a solution. I noticed connection works if I run the node server as http instead of https. Is there any additional steps I should take for a https connection?

Comment: Check Flexible vs Full SSL in your settings. Do you have the origin server SSL settings that you actually need?

Comment: @ArivanBastos What if you run the Node.js server on a port below 1024? like 444?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to node server by doing the follow:

1. Set "key" and "cert" options when instancing https node server: these files can be generated in **Cloud Flare Panel > Select your domain > SSL/TLS > Origin Server**. There was no need for "ca", "requestCert" or "rejectUnauthorized" parameters.
2. Use one of the ports listed in https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/ in the node server. Cloud flare automatically **redirect these ports to the same port in your origin server**.
3. **Allow inbound connections** on the selected port (step 2) in your origin server firewall.
4. Set **SSL setting to FULL** in **Cloud Flare Panel > Select your domain > SSL/TLS > Overview**